Calculate AVERAGEX with all dates in range rather than just dates with data
I'm trying to calculate an average of unique daily users, for each report, over the past 12 months in a DAX measure.
My intention is to calculate unique users each day for each report, and then get the average of that number to represent the average daily users for the 12 month period.
The DAX below calculates that for dates where the report has been used, but does not account for dates where the report was not used at all. Meaning that if a report was used once in the 12 month period, by four people, it's average daily users would show as 4 when it should be much lower.
Can anyone advise how I can make this calculation over all dates in the range, not just all dates where the report has been used?
6.2 average unique daily visitors = CALCULATE(

AVERAGEX(

SUMMARIZE(


'z_Report_usage Report_runs'
 ,'Dates Dim_Dates'[TheDate]
,'z_Report_usage Report_runs'[Folder_Name]
,'z_Report_usage Report_runs'[Report_name]
,"User count", DISTINCTCOUNT('z_Report_usage Report_runs'[User_crsid])

)


,[User count]

)
)


To more accurately get the average of users over a period of time:

Get the overall sum of all users.
Get the number of days in the period.
Divide the sum of users by the count of days.

6.2 average unique daily visitors =

VAR SummarizedTable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'z_Report_usage Report_runs',
        'Dates Dim_Dates'[TheDate],
        'z_Report_usage Report_runs'[Folder_Name],
        'z_Report_usage Report_runs'[Report_name],
        "User count", DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'z_Report_usage Report_runs'[User_crsid] )
    )
VAR UserCount =
    SUMX ( SummarizedTable, [User count] )
VAR DayCount = //Uses the Date Dim table to get the period 
    DATEDIFF (
        MIN ( 'Dates Dim_Dates'[TheDate] ),
        MAX ( 'Dates Dim_Dates'[TheDate] ),
        DAY
    ) + 1 //Number of Days in the period
RETURN
    UserCount / DayCount

